# Can I put a PBX in my office and split my phone line up?

Tags: pbx

If I have a PBX, Asterisk, in my office, and in my office I have a Cisco VoIP phone that my company put in, can I remove the phone and connect my PBX to that incoming line and create a "subnet" of individual telephone services?  Maybe I could reconnect the phone to the pbx in my office?  several other phones?

Comment: Are you an Sysadmin? I wouldn't suggest messing with your companies PBX or putting another PBX on the subnet without checking with them first.

Comment: no but it would be okay as long as I didn't mess up their PBX or hose up the company phone system

Comment: I cringe just thinking about one of my users attempting this. particularly with what a pain it was just getting the PBX up and running initially.

Comment: ah..they'll be alright.

Comment: LOL @johnny....sysadmins complain to much anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to link the two PBX's. You will not be able to just plug in another PBX and have it work. You will also need a switch for the other phones and power adapters if the switch isn't POE.

Comment: since everything is over the same network (voip, data), if I put in the asterisk pbx, connect it to my network jack, can I have it forward or something or is it a tighter integration?

Comment: You may be able to set it up to forward to the other PBX. But either way you would have to tell the initial PBX that connects to your PRI or T1 that there is another PBX on the network and to forward certain calls to it.

Comment: do you mean so the company's pbx would forward to mine?

Comment: yes remember the company's PBX is receiving all incoming traffic first and then sending it to the phones based on extensions. You would need to give your PBX a "extension" although it would not actually be one, then setup a rule on the company's PBX to forward to yours.

Comment: I forget what this "link" is called I will check on the switchvox I have here and get back to you.